# How do I localize to EST data that has no DST?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, dst

I need to read a csv file into python dataframe.

The data is Eastern Standard Time (EST) time-zone WITHOUT Day Light Savings adjustments.

How can I localize the data and convert to UTC? I believe the below assumes DST is in the CSV data timestamps?

```py
csv_bytes   = archive.read(file_name)
data        = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv_bytes),sep=';',header=0,names=['DT',''Close'], parse_dates=['DT'], index_col=['DT'])
data.index = data.index.tz_localize('EST').tz_convert('UTC')
```

Comment: Since EST is not actually a timezone but a UTC offset to be precise, if you set it like you show, you should be fine (better add a test to be sure). "EST" might be commonly used to refer to a timezone, however, here it refers to an entry in the [IANA DB](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).